# How to convert from currency apply addition then use save currency for new sum?

Tags: freemarker

How can I add the following two strings that represent currency (these could be different than en_us currency)?

```
<#assign op1 = '$5.50'>
<#assign op2 = '$1.00'>
<#assign sum = op1 + op2>
```

where sum prints out:  '$6.50'

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but how about:

```
<#-- Calculate the sum: -->
<#assign op1 = 5.50>
<#assign op2 = 1.00>
<#assign sum = op1 + op2>
...
<#-- Later print out the sum: -->
$${sum?string('0.00')}
```

Or if you want to build on Java's currency formatter:

```
${sum?string.currency}
```

BTW, a template that calculates such business data stinks... it's not the duty of the template. The template is to deal with the formatting/visual-design aspects.

Comment: ok cool.  however, the output is "6,5"....that six comma five.  how do I get it to be a decimal?

Comment: agree on the calculation onus but I don't have access to the payload that is coming in .... so I have to improvise and do the calc in the template.

Comment: It depends on your current locale setting, and it seems it's not set to match the page language. In some countries (like mine) the decimal separator is comma. See: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_number_decimal_point